# Is there a shortcut in bash to delete the last segment of a path?

Tags: bash

I've become pretty proficient with a number of bash shortcut keys that make my bash-ing faster: C-a/C-e, C-u, C-w, M-f/M-b, C-r etc. One common task that I haven't found a good shortcut for though is when I want to delete the last segment of a path:

Say I have

```
ls ~/projects/arcaneweb/libraries
```

and I realize I actually meant

```
ls ~/projects/arcaneweb/sources
```

Is there a way to just delete `libraries`, saving a load of keystrokes?

Comment: You're asking about bash, so I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer: In zsh you can accomplish what you want by setting the `WORDCHARS` env variable: `WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS//[-\/]}` (removes - and / from being part of a "word"). I find this very useful so thought I'd share.

Comment: I usually just hit `M-Backspace` repeatedly until desired effect is reached.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A single shortcut: **`M-backspace`**

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

Comment: Wow, that's so obvious! I guess I always assumed this would be the same as C-w for some reason.

Comment: In zsh, you may need to add `bindkey "^[^?" vi-backward-kill-word` to your `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 6):

There is a replace option but not sure it would really save keystrokes unless the path was long.

^abc^xyz

This will replace the first occurrence of abc with xyz.

```
[root~]# ls -l /var/log/messages
-rw-------  1 root root 850312 Dec 28 14:08 /var/log/messages
[root ~]# ^messages^secure
ls -l /var/log/secure
-rw-------  1 root root 652614 Dec 28 14:08 /var/log/secure
```

Bash Shortcut reference:
http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/bash-shortcuts-for-maximum-productivity/

Comment: Oh, that's awesome. Not great for this particular use case, but definitely will be useful elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

M-b,C-k is the quickest I've found, made a bit less so due to needing to use ESC as Meta. If you have Alt/Option bound as Meta, this would be reasonably fast once you develop the muscle memory for it.

Comment: Binding option to meta is the first thing I do when setting up my terminal :). M-b, C-k is pretty good, I think I can get used to that.

Comment: there's also M-b,M-d but all those are for the emacs keybindings, there's also vi-mode

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `unix-filename-rubout` is that it doesn't understand spaces as part of the path.

I came up with this binding (bound to Alt-w):

```
bind '"\ew":"\e[D\e\C-]/\e[C\e\C-d"'
```

The logic is simple:

`\e[D` - `backward-char`

`\e\C-]/` - `character-search-backward` and then `/` (to look for a slash backwards)

`\e[C` - `forward-char`

`\e\C-d` - `shell-kill-word`

The different commands are documented here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html

To query for shortcuts for specific commands, use:

```
bind -q shell-kill-word
```